# Getting 'JsPoolExhaustedException' exception when using ReactJS.Net library - Recommended settings question

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reactjs.net

We are using ReactJS.Net (https://github.com/reactjs/react.net) as part of our .Net 6 web application that is hosted on an Azure App Service.

[image: Screenshot of ReactJS.Net NuGet package]

We have the following configuration within our **Startup.cs** file:

```
app.UseReact(config =>
{
    config
        .SetLoadBabel(false)
        .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/assets/js/kitchensink.server.bundle.js")
        .SetUseDebugReact(StaticConfig.GetValue("CLIENT:React.DebugOutput", false))
        .DisableServerSideRendering()
        .SetMaxEngines(50); //Increased from the default of 25
});
```

However, under an increased load, we are getting the following errors and the site is going down:

```
JSPool.Exceptions.JsPoolExhaustedException:
   at JSPool.JsPool`2.GetEngine (JSPool, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2fc7775f73072640)
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetEngine (React.Core, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at React.ReactEnvironment.get_Engine (React.Core, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78)
   at React.ReactEnvironment.EnsureUserScriptsLoaded (React.Core, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78)
   at React.ReactEnvironment.CreateComponent (React.Core, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78)
   at CLIENT.Cms.App.Extensions.HtmlHelperExtensions.ReactForOptimizely (CLIENT.Cms.App, Version=1.9.16.106, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\BackEnd\CLIENT.Cms.App\Extensions\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs:51)
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared_Components_Header_Default+<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext (CLIENT.Cms.App, Version=1.9.16.106, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\BackEnd\CLIENT.Cms.App\Views\Shared\Components\Header\Default.cshtml:3)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX)
```

From Intellisense, it appears that we can configure the following (along with their default values) in the **Startup.cs** configuration:

- MaxEngines (25)
- MaxUsagesPerEngine (100)
- ReuseJavaScriptEngines
- StartEngines (10)

**Q1. Are there any guidelines for what these could/should be set to in a Production environment with a moderate amount of traffic?**
(i.e. A few thousand users per day - each browsing a small number of pages <--- I appreciate that this isn't very scientific and can get exact stats if it would help)

**Q2. Is there further documentation somewhere about exactly what these settings do and the possible implications of changing them?**

**Q3. Is there something else we may be missing?**